# Rest API responds with html when deployed to heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a rest api without any kind of UI/html files involved. I just want it to respond with some json response body, that's it. I'm using spring for it and java 11. This request works perfectly in localhost and it responds with a JSON body.

```
POST /api/v1/character-info HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:6969
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 75913809-8b11-494f-b5ac-dfd6c3cecbb1

{
    "accountId": "123123",
    "teamNames": [
        "pepper",
        "heath"
    ]
}
```

However, when I deployed my app to heroku, the same request no longer works.I changed `localhost:6969` to `https://myapp.herokuapp.com` and it will reply with this html body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Application Error</title>
        <style media="screen">
          html,body,iframe {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          html,body {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
          iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 0;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I make sure that it will return json instead of HTML?

Here's my controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@PostMapping("/api/v1/character-info")
public CharacterInfoRequest saveTeamNames(@Valid @RequestBody CharacterInfoRequest request) {
    Optional<TosAccount> characterOptional = tosAccountRepository.findByInGameAccountId(request.getAccountId());
    TosAccount character = characterOptional
            .orElseGet(() -> tosAccountService.createTosAccount(request.getAccountId()));

    characterService.updateTeamNames(character, request.getTeamNames());

    return request;
}
```

Help is much appreciated.

Logs from heroku:

```
2020-01-11T16:42:40.304269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=POST path="/api/v1/character-info" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=09a39688-c8a6-4c9a-97cf-75355d2da244 fwd="43.226.7.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2020-01-11T16:48:20.862616+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=c8f8ad30-437a-4683-93aa-0ab37b403a61 fwd="43.226.7.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2020-01-11T16:48:21.239211+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=38de869d-5712-4e8c-b263-fc8e8240df2b fwd="43.226.7.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2020-01-11T16:48:45.871749+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=POST path="/api/v1/character-info" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=befd63a9-3b3b-400f-a559-e4711973960c fwd="43.226.7.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here's my Procfile:

```
worker: java -jar -Dserver.port=$MY_APP_PORT build/libs/*.jar
```

Comment: The HTML returned is an application error from Heroku. What do your application logs say? You can check them with the `heroku logs` command.

Comment: Hi added the logs. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 503 response HTML from Heroku, and the "No web process running" error, are telling you that your web server process is not running so it's not able to serve JSON responses.

You can find more information about Heroku error codes such as this one in the Heroku documentation, for example this error's code is H14: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running

Their documentation suggests to scale up your web process to at least 1 dyno for it to be running. However, I noticed in your Procfile that you don't have a web process listed, you only have worker process. On Heroku, worker processes are not connected to an HTTP endpoint. You'll need to define a web process for that instead.

Try changing your profile to something like:

```
web: java -jar -Dserver.port=$PORT build/libs/*.jar
```

Make sure to commit and deploy this change.

Then, use the Heroku web interface to scale up your web process, or you can use the Heroku Toolbelt if you use the CLI interface:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Comment: I tried what you wrote, but it didn't work sadly. :( I got an error code H10.

Comment: finally made it work. Thank you for the guidance. After doing your suggestion, I changed the procfile to `web: java -jar -Dserver.port=$PORT build/libs/*.jar`.